# Pandas; how to concat two dataframes but only the columns that are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If i have two DataFrames, EX:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['1001','1002','1003','1004'],
          'Place':['Chile','Peru','Colombia','Argentina']})
```

and:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['1001','1002','1003'],
          'Place':['Chile','Peru','Colombia']})
```

How can i concat this two to make one DataFrame of two rows but only with tha columns that are the same? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find the common rows between both dataframes? Didn't get your question, sorry

Comment: Can you include and example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want two rows, namely "Code" and "Place".  ie. you need to transpose the DataFrame:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how="inner").T
print(df)
```